# Where to find a large individual brownie pan?

Tags: baking, equipment, cookware, pan, brownies

I'm looking for a large baking pan for cooking individual square brownies, preferably at least 8cm x 8cm (3.14 inches) but I can't find anything anywhere!! Can anyone suggest where I can get something like this from? Or am I missing something?

I don't want to go for a large tray and then cut them because I want all the brownies to be identical.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be square? Or can it be a loaf shaped rectangle of 64 square cm?

Comment: It's more about each individual brownie ending up the same, ie even sizes and amount of crispyness around the edge. And square is the design I'm going for.

Comment: I can find a ton that are rectangular, several that are square but smaller than you are looking for (about 5cm X 5cm). One more question, do you want individual pans or multiple indentations in a single pan, as in for a muffin tin?  OOH! How about [this](http://www.pfaltzgraff.com/perfect-brownie-pans%2C-set-of-3/K35035929.html?utm_medium=cse&utm_source=amazonshopping&utm_campaign=amazonshopping&tmcampid=23&tmclickref=K35035929&tmad=c&tmplaceref=AMZ&CA_6C15C=530007880000002752)? It's a bit smaller than you want, but not much.

Comment: @bbeckford I too like brownies that are all edges. As jolenealaska pointed out you can get one online, and I suspect your local kitchen wares store sells a similar pan. However if you have a muffin pan, try your recipe in that first. Mine taste good, but the edges did not turn out how I hoped.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has some individual brownie pans that are, I believe, what you may be looking for.

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=individual%20brownie%20pan

Answer (score 0):

I found some, using a search for "square muffin pan":

http://www.bonton.com/shop/home/kitchen/bakeware/cake-pans/wilton-bakeware-12-cavity-brownie-pan_423622.html

http://www.chefsfirst.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=FATMFN-SQR&gclid=CMvVjOKu1cACFcRbfgodyI4AQQ

You might also check a local restaurant supply.

Comment: Look up at comments to the OP.